# Apache commons-logging and thread ID

Tags: java, apache-commons-logging

Is there any way to add a thread ID at the beginning of a log for logs using apache commons-logging without log4j implementation?

I have code which looks similar to an example below but `setProperty` is not taking any effect in log formatting.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class Foo {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getFactory.getInstance(Foo.class);

    public void foo() {

       System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format","[%1$tF %1$tT] [%4$s] %5$s %n");

        ...
        try {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("About to do something to object " + name);
            }
            name.bar();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            log.error("Something bad happened to " + name, e);
        }
        ...
    }
```

PS.
As last round of tests it came up that it has Jdk14Logger

PS2.
It looks that changes to the commons-logging.properites are not taking any effect as well.

Comment: Apache commons loggin is not a loggin library. This is a universal loggin library facade, just like slf4J for example. If you using it on top of log4 or java runtime logging API - configure originating library.

Comment: @VictorGubin How can I find on top of what that commons-logging is running? In imports I see only `apache.commons.logging` but nothing from `java.util.logging.*`

Comment: @VictorGubin Is this what I need to look at: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/java-logging/apache-commons-logging.html

Comment: For the Java out of the box loggin - yes.

Comment: @VictorGubin I have updated OP